# Magento2:graphiql --SyntaxError: Unexpected token < in JSON at position 0

Tags: json, syntax-error, magento2

I am working first time (new to Magento and PHP) with Magento and want to execute graphql using below url from ChromeiQL:
http://localhost:80/magento2/graphql

I am getting exception:

> "SyntaxError: Unexpected token < in JSON at position 0"

Please note - I have not written any code. Just want execute by default code.
As per analysis, I found the reason "Server return as HTML instead of JSON
By-default folder structure (windows 10) is :

```
\wamp64\www\magento2\graphql:
                            - packages
                                       - \codemirror-graphql
                                       - \graphiql
                                       - \graphql-language-server
                                       - \graphql-language-service
                                       - \graphql-language-service-interface
                                       - \graphql-language-service-parser
                                       - \graphql-language-service-server
                                       - \graphql-language-service-types
                                       - \graphql-language-service-utils
                            - proposals
                            - resources
                            - wg-agendas
```

My question:

1. Do I need to install any additional plugin to remove this issue. If yes. what is name of plugin and steps to install.
2. OR which file I need to change the code to remove this issue? Please help in details.

Thanks & Regards

Answer (score -1):

Please read carefully this documentation and follow the steps

```
https://magento-research.github.io/pwa-studio/venia-pwa-concept/setup/
```

I hope You'll able to run both venia-concept theme for PWA and GraphQL too.